# Dovecot/Postfix can't receive emails

Tags: postfix, dovecot

All configurations suggest that everything works ok but i can't receive emails... no errors just

```
status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
```

My main.cf is

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/domain_gr.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/issued/myserver.key
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/domain_gr.ca-bundle
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = domain.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = localhost, localhost.localdomain, localhost, domain.com
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
myorigin = /etc/mailname
inet_protocols = all
home_mailbox = 
#mail_spool_directory = /var/vmail
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
virtual_uid_maps = static:2000
virtual_gid_maps = static:2000
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf
relay_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_relay_domains.cf
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
   permit_mynetworks,
   permit_sasl_authenticated,
   reject_non_fqdn_hostname,
   reject_non_fqdn_sender,
   reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
   reject_unauth_destination,
   reject_unauth_pipelining,
   reject_invalid_hostname
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous

milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891, inet:localhost:8893
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
```

where domain and domain.com are my domains.
Dovecot config is

```
## Dovecot configuration file

# If you're in a hurry, see http://wiki2.dovecot.org/QuickConfiguration

# "doveconf -n" command gives a clean output of the changed settings. Use it
# instead of copy&pasting files when posting to the Dovecot mailing list.

# '#' character and everything after it is treated as comments. Extra spaces
# and tabs are ignored. If you want to use either of these explicitly, put the
# value inside quotes, eg.: key = "# char and trailing whitespace  "

# Most (but not all) settings can be overridden by different protocols and/or
# source/destination IPs by placing the settings inside sections, for example:
# protocol imap { }, local 127.0.0.1 { }, remote 10.0.0.0/8 { }

# Default values are shown for each setting, it's not required to uncomment
# those. These are exceptions to this though: No sections (e.g. namespace {})
# or plugin settings are added by default, they're listed only as examples.
# Paths are also just examples with the real defaults being based on configure
# options. The paths listed here are for configure --prefix=/usr
# --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var

# Enable installed protocols
!include_try /usr/share/dovecot/protocols.d/*.protocol

# A comma separated list of IPs or hosts where to listen in for connections.
# "*" listens in all IPv4 interfaces, "::" listens in all IPv6 interfaces.
# If you want to specify non-default ports or anything more complex,
# edit conf.d/master.conf.
#listen = *, ::

# Base directory where to store runtime data.
#base_dir = /var/run/dovecot/

# Name of this instance. In multi-instance setup doveadm and other commands
# can use -i <instance_name> to select which instance is used (an alternative
# to -c <config_path>). The instance name is also added to Dovecot processes
# in ps output.
#instance_name = dovecot

# Greeting message for clients.
#login_greeting = Dovecot ready.

# Space separated list of trusted network ranges. Connections from these
# IPs are allowed to override their IP addresses and ports (for logging and
# for authentication checks). disable_plaintext_auth is also ignored for
# these networks. Typically you'd specify your IMAP proxy servers here.
#login_trusted_networks =

# Space separated list of login access check sockets (e.g. tcpwrap)
#login_access_sockets =

# With proxy_maybe=yes if proxy destination matches any of these IPs, don't do
# proxying. This isn't necessary normally, but may be useful if the destination
# IP is e.g. a load balancer's IP.
#auth_proxy_self =

# Show more verbose process titles (in ps). Currently shows user name and
# IP address. Useful for seeing who are actually using the IMAP processes
# (eg. shared mailboxes or if same uid is used for multiple accounts).
#verbose_proctitle = no

# Should all processes be killed when Dovecot master process shuts down.
# Setting this to "no" means that Dovecot can be upgraded without
# forcing existing client connections to close (although that could also be
# a problem if the upgrade is e.g. because of a security fix).
#shutdown_clients = yes

# If non-zero, run mail commands via this many connections to doveadm server,
# instead of running them directly in the same process.
#doveadm_worker_count = 0
# UNIX socket or host:port used for connecting to doveadm server
#doveadm_socket_path = doveadm-server

# Space separated list of environment variables that are preserved on Dovecot
# startup and passed down to all of its child processes. You can also give
# key=value pairs to always set specific settings.
#import_environment = TZ

##
## Dictionary server settings
##

# Dictionary can be used to store key=value lists. This is used by several
# plugins. The dictionary can be accessed either directly or though a
# dictionary server. The following dict block maps dictionary names to URIs
# when the server is used. These can then be referenced using URIs in format
# "proxy::<name>".

dict {
  #quota = mysql:/etc/dovecot/dovecot-dict-sql.conf.ext
  #expire = sqlite:/etc/dovecot/dovecot-dict-sql.conf.ext
}

# Most of the actual configuration gets included below. The filenames are
# first sorted by their ASCII value and parsed in that order. The 00-prefixes
# in filenames are intended to make it easier to understand the ordering.
!include conf.d/*.conf

# A config file can also tried to be included without giving an error if
# it's not found:
!include_try local.conf
disable_plaintext_auth = no
mail_location = maildir:/home/vmail/%d/%n/Maildir:INDEX=/home/vmail/%d/%n/Maildir/indexes
auth default {
userdb sql {
args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-mysql.conf
}
passdb sql {
args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-mysql.conf
}
}
```

map files are found here http://serion.co.nz/howto/howto-setup-mailserver-using-postfix-mysql-dovecot-postfixadmin-amavis-new mysql database is standard postfixadmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i needed to change

```
mydestination = localhost, localhost.localdomain, localhost, domain.com
```

to

```
mydestination = localhost, localhost.localdomain
```

and leave

```
home_mailbox
```

empty.

Answer (score 1):

*I know, this is no real answer, but I can't comment at the moment. Sorry.*

This is a setting you can make in the virtual_mailbox_maps directive.

But it is hard to say where exactely the error comes from without the contents of your maps file and the related database.

You could try if delivery is working when you set (an additional) mailbox map in the format of

`address@domain.com  /full/path/to/Maildir`

Comment: Turns out the problem was with directories , i modified and moved everything to correct directory (/home/vmail instead of /var/vmail) but i still can't receive anything. See updated question.
Database is the standard postfixadmin database and the contents of my maps can be found here http://serion.co.nz/howto/howto-setup-mailserver-using-postfix-mysql-dovecot-postfixadmin-amavis-new

Comment: Can you please check if the mail is stored in the correct directory? It should be a file there with a pretty cryptic name

Comment: Apparently it's stored inside /home/username/..... i partially deleted the folder /home/username and it now throws errors. Modifying main.cf to home_mailbox = /home/vmail produces /home/username//home/vmail it append whatever i write to /home/username/